# how to convert a list of string to case class?

Tags: scala

I have a list of string, something like `List("12345:$", "12346:$")`, the only thing I need is the number `"12345"` which before the colon, this is my case class, how can I get the number and convert it to case class? is regex a good way to do that?

```
case class Account(accountId: String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Regex.  Just taking the first element from the result of a `split(":")` would suffice:

```
case class Account(accountId: String)

List("123:$", "456:$").map(s => Account(s.split(":")(0)))
// res1: List[Account] = List(Account("123"), Account("456"))
```

In case Regex is preferred:

```
val pattern = """(\d*):.*""".r

List("123:$", "456:$", "xyz:$").collect{ case pattern(num) => Account(num) }
// res2: List[Account] = List(Account("123"), Account("456"))
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks, and if I wanna have those two, do something like this right? Or is there a better way?
list.map(s => rule(s.split(":")(0), s.split(":")(1)))

Comment: and also, can you tell how to use regex to do that? Because I need to check for the regex pattern and decide which kind data can use the method.

Comment: @mcy, please see expanded answer for a solution using Regex.  Note that `collect` is for filtering out the non-matching elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_222).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class Account(accountId: String)
defined class Account

scala> List("123:$", "456:$").map{ case s"$id:$$" => Account(id) }
res0: List[Account] = List(Account(123), Account(456))
```